# Checking List of String in Groovy

Tags: string, for-loop, groovy

I'm new to groovy and have the following code in testing:

```
groovy> def country_list = [] 
groovy> country_list =['sg', 'ph', 'hk'] 
groovy> for (String item : country_list) { 
groovy>     println item 
groovy>     if (country_list[item].toUpperCase() == "PH") 
groovy>         isPH = true 
groovy> } 
groovy> println isPH
```

When run in console, it throws the exception below:

```
sg
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Exception evaluating property 'sg' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sg for class: java.lang.String
at ConsoleScript6.run(ConsoleScript6:5)
```

What does the error mean ?

I do resolve the issue by this :

```
isPH = ('PH' in country_list) || ('ph' in country_list)
```

But really want to understand the error above.
Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the error is not obvious; anyways the `country_list[item].toUpperCase()` is causing the issue, I guess you want to use `item.toUpperCase()` instead.

Try this:

```
def country_list = [] 
 country_list =['sg', 'ph', 'hk'] 
 for (String item : country_list) { 
     println item 
     if (item.toUpperCase() == "PH") 
         isPH = true 
 } 
 println isPH
```

Run the solution on groovyConsole [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5192285151035392).

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That is because, you have list `country_list`.
But using map notation to fetch the value.

`sg` is the first element in the list of `for` loop. It was assuming to fetch the property `sg` from `country_list` and there is no such property and `sg` only value on the contrary.

Hence the error which is obivious:

> ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   Exception evaluating property 'sg' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sg for class: java.lang.String

You can simple check / assert using below script:

```
def country_list =['sg', 'ph', 'hk']
def isPH = country_list.find { it.toUpperCase() == 'PH' } ? true : false
assert isPH, 'No ph in the list'
println "Is country list contains ph ? $isPH"
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this line ?
`// assert isPH, 'No ph in the list'`
the script can run without it.

Comment: `? and :` works like condition if and else. It can run without assert. But how do you if the script fails? that is why `assert for isPH true`

Comment: `it.toUpperCase() == 'PH' ? true : false` is just `it.toUpperCase() == 'PH'`.  also while OP did not short-circuit, i think it would be a good practice to do so here: `country_list.find { it.toUpperCase() == 'PH' }` gives you either the matching element (truthy) or `null` if not in list in this case.

Comment: @cfrick, agreed, will update your suggestion. I missed. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change `country_list[item]` to `item`.

This is because groovy looks property `sg` for class `ArrayList` since groovy  `Object.getAt(String property)` method returns the value of `property`